# Is it common practive to treat integer overflows as critical errors?

Tags: c, error-handling, integer-overflow, panic

So I am currently working on a low level i386 operating system model. In my fact(x) implementation, which basically computes the factorial of a provided integer. As 12! overflows on 32 bit values, and I can't use 64 bit values, I had to implement a security mechanism to make sure the function doesn't overflow.

Here's the code:

```
#include <libk/stdint.h>
#include <math/math.h>
#include <math/fact.h>

#include <kernel/tty.h>

uint32_t fact(const uint8_t x)
{
  if (x > 11)
  {
    tty_puts("[");
    tty_set_colour(tty_map_colour(VGA_RED, VGA_BLACK));
    tty_puts("FAILED");
    tty_set_colour(tty_map_colour(VGA_LIGHT_GREY, VGA_BLACK));
    tty_puts("] Error: trying to compute a value greater than 11!, aborting");
  }
  #if (MATH_FASTFACT == 1)
  uint32_t _fact_table[12] =
  {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    6,
    24,
    120,
    720,
    5040,
    40320,
    362880,
    3628800,
    39916800
  };
  return (_fact_table[x]);
  #else
  uint32_t res;
  uint8_t i;

  res = 1;
  i = 0;
  while (i <= x)
    res *= (i++);
  return (res);
  #endif
}
```

As you can probably tell, the function first makes sure the provided argument is not greater than 11. If it is, the function displays an error message and calls it a day. My question is: **is it a good practice to treat integer overflows as critical errors and undergo a kernel panic, or should the function return 0?**

Comment: Signed integer overflow is UB, unsigned overflow is not, it's modulo the greatest value + 1.

Comment: Just a small note, 0! = 1. `_fact_table[0]` should be 1

Comment: Entirely depends on whether it should be critical error for your application or it should not.

Comment: It seems that input value `0` will return `0` and you can return zero on overflow as error value, assuming the input is not zero (or declare input of zero an error and return the error return value 0; QED). Now the caller has the task of declaring an emergency or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. However critical it is for the application(or not), I don't think the Kernel should panic. It should just forward the exception to the application by whatever means.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I have no idea why would kernel code calculate factorials. Maybe it is a very critical functionality for it :) Apparently, if it can still live with overflow, panicking wouldn't be appreciated...

Comment: The question is unrelated to your example. Your integer factorial function panics because it is given an input that is not within the range of legal inputs--perfectly reasonable. If some part of your code asks it for 15!, then *that* code is in error, and you'd want to find that fact. Integer overflows themselves may or may not cause a total failure of calculation; that depends on what you're doing.